# Got response data from AFNetworking - now what? (Login/Signup on website via app)

Tags: objective-c, authentication, afnetworking

I want to make a login/signup feature for my iphone program, and I decided to use AFNetworking for it. First I send POST request to the website I want to login at, and then get response data from it.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"myusername", @"password": @"mypassword"};
[manager POST:@"http://website.com/login" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    Data *data = (NSData*)responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

What should I do next in order to authorize myself on the website and get access to the information of the logged in user. The responseObject in my code contains just the html for the login webpage.

Any information would be strongly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this approach i strictly suggest you to use another server module for login. First of all, you could create a sort of Api call method reachable from a client ( eg: /api/login.php ), so passing alle necessaries params. Use https, and/or encrypt username and password with a standard method such as AES-256 or you own custom method (you can also see the OAuth protocol for secure authentication between client and server).
Another way is to use a UIWebView ( for iOS ) or WebView ( for Mac OS ), so calling your webpage you are logged in, it depends from which what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you know how  I could create such Api call method?

Comment: Begin creating a simile php file that expect to receive a POST Value from client, that is needed to identify each Device or user into your server db. Than print his nickname ( if exist ) or whatever you want. Finally print received data from server on client through Afnetworking http response data. It could be a good beginning point in the Magic world of Api call ;)